# echo single column varchar value to parquet without spark

Tags: java, parquet

I am looking to create a simple one column (animal varchar(20)) parquet file but dont want to setup spark.etc

Want to be able to do some one-liner like echo "frog" > new.parquet

Is there any such simple tool that exists for this?

Comment: beeline is a tool that can let you do that. You still need to execute a command to create the table (as parquet) with a single column schema before you can add your "frog".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Apache Arrow to do this, see http://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/parquet.html